# qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" This application failed to start because

Tags: python, ui

Скрипт:

```
import sys  # sys нужен для передачи argv в QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import design  # Это наш конвертированный файл дизайна

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации нашего дизайна

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()  # и запускаем приложение

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если мы запускаем файл напрямую, а не импортируем
    main()  # то запускаем функцию main()
```

design.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(390, 359)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Login = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Login.setEnabled(True)
        self.Login.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 181, 91))
        self.Login.setObjectName("Login")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Login.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

И содержимое папки  C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools
Вот такое:
[image: капец]

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Заработало:
Перенёс папку platforms из C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins

В C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\